# Switch using woocommerce.php to default woocommerce templates in child theme

Tags: php, woocommerce, woothemes

I have an issue which is very weird,
The parent theme is using woocommerce.php to display shop and single-product pages.

Now i need to change this as I have to make specifice changes in single-product.php and content-single-product.php as well as archive-product.php so basically a major overhaul.

I'm not allowed to changed the parent theme as it is a premium theme and will generated problems on future updates. So How do I go about stopping the use of woocommerce.php from the child theme.

Comment: I think I may be missing something, couldn't you just override the parent theme's template files in the child theme?

Comment: Yes I can but the thing is the parent theme uses woocommerce.php as described here http://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/ what it does is basically use woocommerce_content(); to generate output for archive and single pages, this doesn't use the single-product.php templates or archive-product.php, so any hooks i want to use on those pages i can't.